# Is there a default XML line to resize textSize if the current textSize does not fit the borders of the TextView?

Tags: android, xml, resize

I'm working on a project that displays sentences, but sometimes the sentences are too long to fit at a given textSize. The textSize is at a size that I like, not too small for short sentences, but when the sentences pass the borders of the TextView the text disappears. I know I *could* make it end in '...' but then the sentence is still not read.

So I am looking for a way to decrease textSize ONLY when the text exceeds the TextView borders.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoResizeTextView, which changes text size depending on the textview size.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/5050338

Comment: Dang, I did see that but I was hoping there would be an already integrated version. I'll give it a shot anyway, thanks!

Comment: There is not so far. Autoresize tv works pretty well and its easy to implement. Hope it helps!